# Auto complete nao funciona asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Tenho uma tabela no banco chamado Disciplinas,  e tenho um campo buscar na minha Index que se eu digitar uma letra"A" devia sugerir "Analise  e desenvolvimento" isso é um exemplo, porem não funciona, aparentemente o codigo esta certo mas não está sugerindo  nada quando digito uma letra.

Model disciplina Metodo que uso para listar as disciplinas:

```
        public static List<Disciplina> listaDisciplina()
    {

        SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["minhaConexao"].ConnectionString);

        conexao.Open();

        string select = "SELECT * FROM Disciplina ";

        SqlCommand selectComando = new SqlCommand(select, conexao);

        SqlDataReader sqlReader = selectComando.ExecuteReader();

        List<Disciplina> DisciplianadeAlunos = new List<Disciplina>();

        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            DisciplianadeAlunos.Add(new Disciplina(int.Parse(sqlReader["idDisciplina"].ToString()),
                                            sqlReader["NomeDisciplina"].ToString(),
                                            sqlReader["Semestre"].ToString(),
                                            sqlReader["Curso"].ToString()));// fim add
        }



        return DisciplianadeAlunos;

    }
```

Meu metodo que uso no auto complete reaproveita meu listaDisciplinas, trazendo uma lsita de disciplinas:

```
        public static List<String> buscaDisciplina(string term)
    {

        return listaDisciplina()
            .Where(p => p.NomeDisciplina.StartsWith(term, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .Select(p => p.NomeDisciplina).ToList();
    }
```

Meu Disciplinas Controller:

```
        public ActionResult buscaDisciplina(string term)
    {
        return Json(Disciplina.buscaDisciplina(term), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Meu index

```
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#campoBusca").autocomplete({

          source: '@Url.Action("buscaDisciplina", "Disciplina")'
    });
});
</script>
```

Meu campo de busca dentro do nav bar

```
               <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
               <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="campoBusca" type="text" placeholder="Buscar">
               @*<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>*@
           </form>
```

Comment: Você colocou um break point na sua action no controller pra ver se a requisição está batendo lá dentro?

Comment: Coloquei, e pior q quando digito uma letra nem se quer chama minha action =/

Comment: Certo, então o problema provavelmente está na url. Tenta ao invés de `'@Url.Action("buscaDisciplina", "Disciplina")'` colocar '/NomeDoController/NomeDaAction', faz o teste e me fala.

Comment: Sem efeito , eu fiz um inspecionar elemento, mas dis "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function". problema com banco não é pq todas outras coisas estão puxando certo, menos meu auto complete

Comment: Neste caso o autocomplete está nulo. Você adicionou a biblioteca do autocomplete do jquery?

Comment: isso resolvi parou erro relaciona jquery eu só adicionei as blibiotecas direto no Bundle, mas mesmo assim não vai provavelmente algum detalhe não está deixando chamar o auto complete, mas valeu se eu descobrir eu aviso.

Comment: Achei problema faltou  , "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js e esse  "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" agora ta certo